# How to select the last record of a time line by a specific time and another condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a simple table with a time line of tickets and a state.

```
Id = unique Id column (auto increment)
Time = Time where state changed (always ascending in combination this the id)
IdTicket = Identifier
IdState = State of ticket object
```

The information I need is to know the state of tickets at a specific time. There fore I use this query:

```
SELECT t.[IdTicket], [IdState]
FROM [tbl] AS t WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN 
(
  SELECT [IdTicket], MAX([Time]) AS [Time] 
  FROM [tbl] AS t WITH (NOLOCK) 
  WHERE [Time]<'20121213 00:00:00' 
  GROUP BY [IdTicket]
) AS tMax ON t.[IdTicket]=tMax.[IdTicket] AND t.[Time]=tMax.[Time]
```

This works as long as the [Time] entries are different. Now I have the case that the state of a IdTicket changes more than once in a second. In other words the [Time] entry is equal and the INNER JOIN results in 2 or more entries for one ticket.

Now I also now, that the unique Id is ascending too. If I can modify the inner query, that it searches the MAX([Time]) entry and if it is equal it should return the record as a maximum that has the higher [Id].

One idea was to combine the Date Time and the ID into a string like this 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss iiiiiiiiii' and take the maximum of this. Where iiiiiiiiii is may unique ascending Id.

This is the modified statement that seam to work:

```
SELECT t.[IdTicket], [IdState]
FROM [tbl] AS t WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN 
(
  SELECT [IdTicket], MAX(CONVERT(VARCHAR,[Time],21) + FORMAT([Id],'0000000000')) AS [Time_Id] 
  FROM [tbl] AS t WITH (NOLOCK) 
  WHERE [Time]<'20121213 00:00:00' 
  GROUP BY [IdTicket]
) AS tMax ON t.[Id]=RIGHT(tMax.[Time_Id],10)
```

The text conversion looks slow and complicated to me. So is there is simpler way instead of combining the Date and time to one value as a string?